# Amazon S3 for Authenticated User in Android?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I got many reference for Unauthorised login, how to achieve for Authorised members. I am new in AWS, I am getting IdentityId and AWS Key and Secret key for Unauthorised. From my Server I am getting BucketName, IdentityId,Token how to put that in code - AP_SOUTH_1

```
 private static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider sCredProvider;
 sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context.getApplicationContext(),
                Constants.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
                Regions.fromName(Constants.COGNITO_POOL_REGION));

Log.e("MSG ID2", sCredProvider.getIdentityId()+" "+sCredProvider.getCachedIdentityId());

Log.e("MSG ID3", sCredProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId()+" "
             +sCredProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey());

HashMap<String, String> loginsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    loginsMap.put(Constants.URL_KEY, Constants.COGNITO_TOKEN);
```

What after this If I pass `hahMap` app crashed with error ,IdentityId mention not found. But Id is there and working from server.
Second way I Tried by Docs in AWS was `DeveloperAuthenticationProvider`  in that I provided TOKEN and IDENTITY ID but still same Error INVALID TOKEN

Comment: Which region are you using?

Comment: @Nisarg AP_SOUTH_1

Comment: Did you try Regions.AP_SOUTH_1 ?

Comment: @Nisarg Yes tried, ont the server its same can you tell the complete process  after HasMap ?

Comment: @Nisarg Solved- App Server was sending wrong token, now uploading files is working Thanks